# Bottom align on flexbox with grow

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm trying to create a three row layout using flexbox which is responsive (there can be multiple columns of three rows).

[image: MockupOfGoal]

The second row (dark blue boxes) should auto-grow in order to accommodate the number of `li` inside.

The bottom row should always be aligned to the bottom of the page, so that the words Unserved penalties are aligned between both columns (there may be more columns but two seems like a good sample).

I've tried various things,

- Setting the bottom div as `absolute` and `bottom: 0` all that seems to do is cause it to show on top of the second row.
- Setting `align-self` to both end and baseline - it doesn't seem to do anything so there is a good chance I'm using it wrong

The trouble I'm running into is aligning the "Unserved Penalties" div to the bottom of the parent div.

Any help would be appreciated - I'm trying to do this without the use of JS if possible, using CSS only.

I've uploaded a simplified fiddle of this here http://jsfiddle.net/zor3pfxw/

I have tried using bootstrap but can't get it to make the two divs side by side (Team A and Team B) the same size, so switched to flexbox to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mitch take a look at this updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zor3pfxw/57/

Edited the following CSS to be

```
.playerNumbers {
  overflow: auto;
  flex:1;
}

.team-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 25%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

I made .team-container a flex element and direction of column. I then made its child element .playersNumber have a flex:1 property. This tells it to take all the available space when it sibling elements do not have a flex property associated with it. By default the flex property is flex:0, meaning it will take the normal element space

Quote from http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/flexbox-next-generation-css-layout-arrived

> FLEX
>
> The flex property is applied to flex items. It’s a shorthand property
>   that combines the flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis properties
>   into one declaration. The flex-grow and flex-shrink properties both
>   take a unitless value that defines how much space each element should
>   take up in proportion to one another. By default, flex-grow is 0 and
>   flex-shrink is 1, meaning that all the elements will be in proportion
>   to one another. The flex-basis property defines the size of elements
>   before extra space is distributed and its default value is auto.
>
> The latter two properties are optional, so if we simply apply the
>   declaration flex: 1; to the .nav class, it changes the flex-grow value
>   to 1. The other flex item in the same flex container is the h1 element
>   with the class .logo, and since flex-grow is 0 by default, the .nav
>   will always take up more space than the .logo.

Another decent blog post on flexbox http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/